# How do I count the number of occurances each value appears in column with pandas?

Tags: pandas

I would like to count the number of occurrances each university appears in the Institution column.

Here is my list:

```
Institution 
Stanford University
University of Southern California
Harvard University
Harvard University
Ohio State University
University of Southern California
University of Southern California
```

I wrote this, but I am not sure what is the correct way:

```
df.value_counts(df['Institution'].values, sort=False)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

It is a method of a Series, hence:

```
df['Institution'].value_counts(sort=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
df.groupby('Institution').size()
```